# Processing in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way to make R, using RStudio use more than 50% (roughly) of the processor when I run some script?
I am executing an R script, it takes some time until it finishes, I checked the CPU usage of the processor from time to time and in all the times the R session that executed the script did not use more than 50% of the processor, I would like to know if it can be configured to use more than 50% of the processor

Comment: Probably you have to parallelize your code, by opening a cluster, splitting your operations into small pieces, and pass each piece to a node of the cluster. there are several function in R to do this. Just to mention a few packages: `parallel`, `snow`, `snowfall`, `future`, `furrr` ecc

Comment: I will try to verify them, thanks